# Ruby constant double pipe equals value vs. defined? constant

Tags: ruby, constants

Double pipe equals:

```
MY_CONST ||= 42
```

Operator defined?:

```
MY_CONST = 42 unless defined? MY_CONST
```

Why the second way is overwhelmingly more common? Is there any drawbacks in the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general (constant and variables) case, if `MY_CONST` is `false` or `nil`, then it would be assigned to 42.

Specific to the constant case, you shouldn't be reassigning constants (though Ruby will allow you to); the `defined?` check sees if the constant has been declared yet.

To demonstrate both problems:

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > MY_CONST = false
 => false
2.0.0-p353 :002 > MY_CONST ||= 42
(irb):2: warning: already initialized constant MY_CONST
(irb):1: warning: previous definition of MY_CONST was here
 => 42
2.0.0-p353 :003 > MY_CONST
 => 42
```

Comment: Okay. Though it's more universal, still looks mad to me as the amount of constants containing nil or false is negligibly small.

Comment: "the amount of constants containing nil or false is negligibly small", well, that depends on the code base doesn't it? It's entirely conceivable that someone would need to define a bunch of constants that have a large number of nil or false values, at least to me.